# Jquery fill in content of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class=“phpversion”></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/core/components/seo/templates/default/functions/generic/php-version.php",
                    success:function(result){
$( "div.phpversion” ).html(result);
                    }
                });             
            });
</script>
```

The aim is to fill in the div with class phpversion with the result obtained.

When I use "alert(result);" instead of "$( "div.phpversion” ).html(result);", the popup box with the expected value displays on load of the page.

Can you please help :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using wrong double-quote symbol. You're using the “ symbol instead of " symbol (3 times in your snippet)

Comment: The IDE was changing them on save ... didn't notice! As soon as I changed them it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ID for that div and update the JavaScript code accordingly:

```html
<div id="phpversion"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
             url:"/core/components/seo/templates/default/functions/generic/php-version.php",
                    success:function(result){
$( "#phpversion" ).text(result);
                    }
                });             
            });
</script>
```

Comment: use .text() instead of .html()

Comment: It still doesn't work and when I click on "Run Code Snippet" it gives an error.

Comment: this snippet won't work because the url is hosted on your page!

Comment: @MarcinC. you are right re the URL. But it still doesn't work on my page ... ;/

Comment: changed the code, look at the quotes, they used to be different